# How to enter BIOS on Windows 10 Laptop that fails to boot with previously Fast Boot setting enabled?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, uefi

There are a few related questions on this forum e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1068056/how-to-enter-uefi-bios-on-acer-aspire-one-when-windows-10-has-disabled-f2) & [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1016274/how-do-i-enter-the-bios-on-windows-10), however I am still considering a slightly different situation.

On a Windows 10 Laptop with Fast Boot enabled, the laptop does not Cold Boot unless you fully restart it..

In such a scenario in order to access BIOS (UEFI Setup) you need to disable Fast Boot or fully restart the laptop from within Windows 10,  only then at POST stage (generally) F2 key works and you enter the BIOS. Alternatively you instruct it to enter UEFI upon restart in Recovery Settings.

However I am looking at a situation where in Windows 10 Fast Boot was enabled and it attempts to Fast Boot but fails for any reasons like corrupt files or bad drive or so on.

Now Windows 10 is not booting and in this case how can I enter the BIOS? Would F2 key or any other alternative work?

How to enter BIOS on Windows 10 Laptop that fails to boot with previously Fast Boot setting enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unplug the power cord from the wall socket and remove the battery.
Press and hold the power button for 20 seconds.
Now return the battery and plug the laptop back in.

When you now boot up, pressing the BIOS access key should work.

The reason is that killing all power and draining any residual should take the laptop
out of the hybrid sleep mode it is stuck in, so it can do a real cold start.

Comment: This works. On my Acer Travelmate B laptop, battery however is not detachable component. It's inside the back panel which is not serviceable by user. However Acer has provided a special switch inside a pin hole that you can long press for 5 - 6 seconds using a needle or a paperclip and it simulates removal and re-insertion of battery. I tried that pinhole paperclip trick and it worked. Upon next reboot F2 took me into UEFI. This will come in handy in future if for any reasons my Windows 10 fails to boot and I need to externally boot it using rescue/recovery disks or so.Thank you very much.